# Visualizar mi página web en construcción desde el móvil ¿Es posible?¿Cómo?

Tags: html, css, responsive

Estoy haciendo un página web y me gustaría saber si se puede visualizar desde el móvil mientras aún la estoy creando. Las sensaciones de poner el tamaño a escala en el pc a verlo en el móvil son muy distintas...

Comment: Quieres que se vea en móvil mientras que si la abren desde una pc no la deje ver?

Comment: nono, quiero transportar los archivos al movil apra verla desde el móvil mientras la estoy diseñando. Transportando los archivos al móvil no me a dejado..

Comment: Si estás en Chrome  puedes abrir el inspector. En la esquina izquierda arriba del inspector hay un ícono que parece un móvil y un iPad. Si haces click en este ícono puedes ver como queda tu página web en un móvil. También te deja trabajar con "eventos táctiles" o sea tu utilizas el ratón pero puedes probar tus eventos táctiles..

Answer (score 1):

Si tienes Un telefono Android puedes usar Chrome para depurar

1. activa las opciones de Desarrollador (si no estan tienes que tocar 7 veces el Número de compilación en "Acerca del dispositivo")
2. En las opciones de desarrollador activa la opcion Depuracion USB
3. Conecta tu telefono por cable USB
4. En el Chrome de tu PC ve a `chrome://inspect` veras que aparece una alerta en tu celular

Listo ahora tienes conectado tu celular para ver lo que tienes en chrome

Answer (score 0):

No sé cómo la estás diseñando, pero si es `html, css y js` basta con que lo subas a un servidor (no importa si es gratuito como hostinger, 260mb, nixiweb o cdmon).

Ahora también podrías subirlo a **codepen.io** o **jsfiddle**, excepto si usas php, para eso tienes **codenvy**.

En lo personal, uso más codepen.io y su modo `"debug"` para hacer precisamente estos test via celular, que también los realizo via **DevTool** de chrome y su **Toogle Device Tolbar**

↓ *El botón en la esquina superior izquierda* 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero la experiencia de verlo directamente en un móvil es completamente distinta, que es lo que quieres **probar directamente al principio lo puedes lograr creando un proyecto de codepen** y ya al final lo subo a mi propio servidor en **siteground**.

Que por cierto si te vas a dedicar a este mundillo, lo mejor es que ya tengas tu propio dominio y hosting, no te gastaras más de 100 dólares anualmente y con un mínimo de un solo cliente al año, lo recuperas.